# Complex CakePHP queries

Tags: cakephp

I need a data-filter based on a child model HABTM relation condition.

My table structure is as following:

Project hasMany TaskGroup hasMany Task hasAndBelongsToMany User.

I need my find function to get only the Projects with specific TaskGroups that contain Tasks assigned to some User.id. In other words, I need my Tasks filtered by User.id, and structured as Project -> TaskGroup -> Task. Is there a way Cake model bindings handle this, or do I need to write the joins manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use Joins - see link for how to build joins in CakePHP:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables